# In "nicht nur ... sondern" construction, which part should a verb agree with?

Tags: grammatical-number

> ... dass **nicht nur** Felix, **sondern** jeder einzelne Einwohner erschossen worden ***ist/sind***?

I wonder if the verb "sein" at the end should agree with the singular "Felix" or the singular "jeder einzelne Einwohner"? Or should I add these two parts together in a manner of speaking and use the plural form *sind*?

Comment: Your example is a little bit unlucky, as also *jeder einzelne Einwohner* would ask for singular: *Jeder einzelne Einwohner wurde erschossen.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, as others answered, "ist" is totally correct, as it matches both parts.

If you slightly adjust your example, you would usually have to match the **second** part, although this may sound weird in some cases:

> ... dass nicht nur Felix, sondern **alle** Einwohner erschossen worden **sind**.
>
> ... dass nicht nur alle Einwohner, sondern auch **das Maskottchen** erschossen worden **ist**.

Also see this [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-11481) (in german), where also other cases than "nicht nur... sondern auch" are explained.

Answer (score 0):

Use the word "ist", because the word **einzelne** emphasises the singular.

Comment: In my eyes the word "auch" after 'sondern' is missing. It makes the choice for correct form easier.

Answer (score 0):

It should agree with both parts of the sentence. The form you want is "ist." This agrees With "Felix" in the first part of the sentence. It also agrees with "jeder einzelne" in the second part.

It appears not to agree with "Einwohner," which is a "collective noun" that refers to "jeder einzelne," which is singular.