# Ein Satz ohne das Verb "sein"

Tags: standard-german

Gestern habe ich ein Musikstück von Helene Fischer gehört und ich bin dort auf einen seltsamen Satz gestoßen. Helene hat gesagt:

> Der Tisch gedeckt, der Wein schon kalt

Ich habe mich gefragt, warum "gedeckt" ohne "sein" (das Verb) benutzt worden ist.

Und sagen Sie mir bitte auch, ob dieser Satz grammatisch richtig ist.

Comment: Der betreffende Satz lautet vollständig: _Der Tisch gedeckt, der Wein schon kalt, aber du bist noch nicht da._ Vielleicht wollen Sie das noch ergänzen? Bei solchen Fragen ist es für Antwortende immer hilfreich, wenn sie zumindest den vollständigen Satz zur Verfügung haben :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In der Poesie ist es möglich (und üblich), Satzteile wegzulassen, die im normalen Sprachverkehr unverzichtbar wären.

Die Verszeile

> Der Tisch gedeckt, der Wein schon kalt

ist so ein Fall, wo der Dichter (hier: der Texter des Lieds) zu diesem Ausdrucksmittel gegriffen hat.

Man kann stilistische und technische Gründe dafür haben: Technisch: Mit dem Weglassen von Wörtern oder Silben kann man möglicherweise ein gegebenes Versmaß besser einhalten. Stilistisch: Je kürzer und knapper ein Ausdruck, desto besser, denn dadurch wird der Text dichter. Und man spricht ja nicht umsonst von ***Dichtung***.

Das Weglassen von Satzteilen ist ein exklusives Merkmal dichterischer Sprache. Es kommt aber auch in Redewendungen vor (die man aber auch zur Dichtung zählen kann):

> Ein Mann, ein Wort!
>
> Wie der Herr so's G'scherr.
>
> Jedem Tierchen sein Pläsierchen.
>
> Vom Regen in die Traufe.

Hier fehlt überall das Verb. Weggelassen werden stets Satzteile, die *semantisch* überflüssig sind, insofern als der normale Rezipient sie annehmbarerweise von selber (unbewusst) ergänzen wird. Sofern es Verben sind, die wegfallen, sind es Verben von sehr allgemeinem, unspezifischem Inhalt, also Dinge wie "sein", "haben", "kommen", etc.

Answer (score 3):

Dies ist ein rhetorisches Mittel genannt Ellipse.

Zitat Wikipedia:

> Als Ellipse (von altgriechisch ἔλλειψις élleipsis, deutsch
>   ‚Zurücklassen, Unterlassen, Auslassen‘) bezeichnet man in der
>   Linguistik das Auslassen von Satzteilen, aber auch die Sätze mit
>   diesen Auslassungen. Häufig wird das Prädikat ausgelassen.

[Wikipedia: Ellipse (Linguistik)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik))

Dies soll den Text konzentrieren/komprimieren. Das Prädikat muss dabei aus dem Kontext erschließbar sein.

Answer (score 0):

Dies ist eine Phrase, die das *da sein* aus dem Matrixsatz genauer beschreibt.

> du bist da
>
> du bist noch nicht da
>
> du bist noch nicht da aber der Tisch gedeckt

Das ist eine relativ komplizierte Konstruktion, daher könnte man geneigt sein, die Phrase als Ellipse zu beschreiben. Das Gegenteil ist aber der Fall.

Denn Sätze wie *Karl geht schoppen, aber Max und Moritz nicht* sind nichts unübliches. Das Einfügen eines korrekt flektierten Verbes wird dabei in der Regel angestrebt, ist aber zumindest dann nicht nötig, wenn der Genus beider Subjekte gleich lautet, *Max spielt Playstation, Moritz X-Box*. Diese Konstruktion nennt sich Anapher. Die Anapher wird in aller Regel ins Nachfeld gerückt.

In deinem Beispielsatz wurde der Ausdruck umgekehrt und die korrekte Flexion verletzt.

Das ist einerseits nichts schmerzliches, zumal *ge-* gewissermaßen Verbcharacter trägt: vgl *Tischgedeck* das was den Tisch deckt, *Tischdecke* - Decke des Tisches, bzw. *die den Tisch deckt*, vgl *der mit dem Wolf tanzt*; konsequent widerum *Tischgedeck* - Gedeck des Tisches, bzw. das den Tisch gedeckt [hat], siehe dazu auf SE: "dass Saladin" [Nathan der Weise; ToDo: linky].

Andererseits ist die Umstellung zulässig, insofern eben kein sachlicher Zusammenhang ausgedrückt wird, sowie der zeitliche Zusammenhang gezwungener Maßen parallel verläuft (Geometriehausaufgabe: ist ein Punkt parallel zu einer Un-Geraden?).

Ich denke, ich habe das Thema verfehlt. Ich wollte nur meine Ansicht erkunden und einen Ausblick darauf geben, was Ellipse eigentlich bedeutet.

PS: siehe zu uneinheitlicher Flexion hinsichtlich gemischter Genüsse bspw auch: ["nicht nur X, sondern auch Y und Z haben"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/in-nicht-nur-sondern-construction-which-part-should-a-verb-agree-with); Denn dort wird *nicht nur Y und Z, sonder auch X" als normal eingestuft. Derlei Probleme werden immer wieder erfragt.

Comment: Welche Rolle spielt das Genus der Subjekte? Inwiefern ist *Max spielt Playstation, Moritz X-Box* eine Anapher? Wo ist dort ein Nachfeld? Was ist das Gegenteil einer Ellipse? Wem hilft dieser Wortsalat?

Comment: @DavidVogt das sind einmal alle Unsicherheiten, die mir beim Schreiben doch nicht all zu wichtig erschienen. Ich versuche zu antworten a) eben nix (s. Link im Update) b) Was ist das Gegenteil einer Katze? c) Ja, Nachfeld lernte ich eigentlich im Zusammenhang mit einer von Tofro, SE-User, dargestellten Phrasenart, jener wie eben ", SE-User,", die ich gerne mit dieser hier verwegsle; Im Prinzip denke ich, dort ist ein Feld und das kommt nach: Ein Nachfeld eben d) k.A. e) zu allererst mir.